Isotope enrichment, NRC, and free speech
Let's say a person had a couple new potential isotope enrichment techniques which they would like to reveal to the world.
In the United States, can they be shared openly under the First Amendment?
Presuming the isotope enrichment techniques do not constitute a true threat, (as the techniques have no intentions behind them) could they be classified as academic discussion, and would any related discussion pertaining to amateur nuclear reactors also be considered free speech?

Are you asking if writing an academic article in physics is prohibited? Why would you think so?

@littleadv People seem to flip out about my theoretical exploration and inquiry upon isotope enrichment techniques

@littleadv Because there's specific laws about nuclear technologies.

@user71659 Aha! Yes, here it is: "According to current DOE procedures, research and development on methods of isotope separation other than gaseous diffusion or gas centrifuge can be carried out on an unclassified basis until that research shows a “reasonable potential for the separation of practical quantities of special nuclear material.”

@user71659 If you make a formal answer for this post, I will accept it

Edited to remove the reason for closing, incorporated feedback into accepted answer.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


In the United States, can they be shared openly under the First Amendment?

The Atomic Energy Act of 1954 specifies as secret, "all data concerning the production of special nuclear material."
However, according to current DOE procedures, research and development on methods of isotope separation other than gaseous diffusion or gas centrifuge can be carried out on an unclassified basis until that research shows a "reasonable potential for the separation of practical quantities of special nuclear material."
You can find more information and additional links here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_secret
It's worth noting that the Wikipedia article mentions that the US government itself says that this approach is controversial and may be unconstitutional.
Additionally, while information on what and how much is being produced may well be secret, details of the Calutrons used in WW2, and any number of proposed methods (say laser-based isotope separation) have been openly published over many decades. 42 USC Division A is very nuanced on this matter.
